# How to make google indexing a URL with an hash

Tags: javascript, indexing, hash

I have a page with internal anchors, basically one page scrolling. 
The main sections of the page are defined by these anchors and thus there are hashes such as #section-title

I'd like google to index those peaces of content storing the URLs with the hashes. I know that by default google doesn't, but if you use an hashbang (#!) it does. The problem with hashbang is that that technic is now deprecated, and as far as I know, there is only a new method developed by Google for indexing Ajax applications through an HTML snapshot, but it's defenilty not my case, since I have a normal static HTML page.

So, is there another way maybe I can tell google to index those URLs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way....

I created a rewriteRule in the .htaccess where I have different cleaned URLs for all the sections I want Google to Index. They all point to the same page, then JS takes care to scroll them to the related peace of content in according to the last URL fragment